# What is the purpose of "account-plugin-facebook" package?

Tags: 16.04, package-management, plugins, facebook

I am using a PC that runs on **Ubuntu 16.04**. While I was browsing the packages that have been installed, I found this one "***account-plugin-facebook***" (in addition to many other similar packages like *account-plugin-flikr*, *account-plugin-google*...) although I didn't install anyone of them.
My question is: **What are these packages for? and can I remove them without any harming my PC?**
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [GNOME Control Center account plugin](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gnome/account-plugin-facebook) for single signon - facebook.

Which means it is used if you want to login to your facebook account via gnome. I cannot tell you if it can be uninstalled without problems as I use KDE and do not have such a package, but if you try uninstalling it and it does not try to remove a ton of other packages, you should be safe.